# I want to reorder/edit an existing INI file

Tags: c#

What I need to do next is to delete the data that is created into the INI and re-number the Panels, the delete works but I don't seems to figure out how to re-number the panels, here is an idea. My app is making a INi file saving data like this:

```
[Panel - 1]
Name=A name
Link=A link
[PanelCount]
Count=3
[Panel - 2]
Name=B name
Link=B link
[Panel - 3]
Name=C name
Link=C link
```

Now if I delete for example Panel 2 I get a result like this:

```
[Panel - 1]
Name=A name
Link=A link
[PanelCount]
Count=2
[Panel - 3]
Name=C name
Link=C link
```

The Count form PanelCount is decreasing but the Panels now are 1 and 3, I want to modify all that are greater then what I've deleted.

And I want to put the PanelCount tab to always be last, it seems like it's always second for some reason.

What I want to get is:

```
[Panel - 1]
Name=A name
Link=A link
[Panel - 2]
Name=C name
Link=C link
[PanelCount]
Count=2
```

Here is the Write C code:

```
    public void Write(string section, string key, string value)
    {
        WritePrivateProfileString(section, key, value, this.filePath);
    }
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        INIFile ini = new INIFile("config.ini");
        Int32.TryParse(ini.Read("PanelCount", "Count"),out i);
        int panelCount = flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Count-1;
        if(f2.Ok == true)
        {
            ini.Write("Panel - " + i, "Name", laB.Text);
            ini.Write("Panel - " + i, "Link", laB.Name);
            ini.Write("PanelCount", "Count", panelCount.ToString());
        }
    }
```

And here is what I've tried  to get this work:

```
    public string Read(string section, string key)
    {
        StringBuilder SB = new StringBuilder(255);
        int i = GetPrivateProfileString(section, key, "", SB, 255, this.filePath);
        return SB.ToString();
    }

    private void picB_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string del = flp.Name;
        INIFile ini = new INIFile("config.ini");
        int PanelCount = int.Parse(ini.Read("PanelCount", "Count"));
        int count = PanelCount;
        //ini.DeleteSection("Panel - " + del);
        int loc = 0;
        //int.TryParse(del, out loc);
        count--;
        for (int i = 1; i <= loc;i++ )
        {
            //ini.Write("Panel - " + del);
        }
        ini.Write("PanelCount", "Count", count.ToString());
    }
```

Comment: the code you show only write one panel and a count

Comment: Yes for every click it makes a panel, that way i can make multiple panels. when i delete one of that panels that creates i get that result and i need to re-order them in order for my read to work properly.

Comment: you are going to have to rewrite the whole file

Comment: I cant do that, i will loose the data.It has to be a way to edit it.

Comment: read the whole file in, change it and then write it out

Comment: That's what i try to do but i dont seem to figure out how to do it. here is how i tried it:
            string del = flp.Name;
            INIFile ini = new INIFile("config.ini");
            int PanelCount = int.Parse(ini.Read("PanelCount", "Count"));
            int count = PanelCount;
            //ini.DeleteSection("Panel - " + del);
            int loc = 0;
            count--;
            for (int i = 1; i <= loc;i++ )
            {
                //ini.Write("Panel - " + del);
            }
            ini.Write("PanelCount", "Count", count.ToString());

Comment: u gonna have to put that in the question - cant read it in a comment

Comment: Done, I've put it in question.